# What is the positive integer number $n$ satisfying $(2n)!=n!\times(n+1)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

> What is the positive integer number  $n$  satisfying 
>   $(2n)!=n!\times(n+1)!$

I tried to expand the factorial  but it didn't help much ?

Comment: There has only $n=1$.

Comment: @ntt  how?  Trying or algebraic solution?

Comment: Expanding the factorial helps a lot if you are familiar with Bertrand's postulate and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: @Arthur  can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: @prayer smith you only need the definition of factorial and the trivial fact $\frac{n+k-1}{k}>1$ for all $n>1$, $k\geqslant 1$.

Comment: @ntt: what about $n=0$ ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust it is mentioned that positive integer number.

Comment: @ntt: you are, right, I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest reason that you can't have any other solution (except $n=1$) is that $(2n)!$ is just too big.

The equation is equivalent to $(2n)!/(n!\times n!)=n+1$. This can be written (by expanding and cancelling) as

$$\frac{2n}{n}\times\frac{2n-1}{n-1}\times\cdots\times\frac{n+1}1=n+1.$$

Now it's awkward to calculate the LHS exactly, but much easier to show it's too big (if $n>1$). Each of the fractions is at least $2$ and there are $n$ of them, so we have $\text{LHS}\geq 2^n$. If $n>1$ then $2^n>n+1$, so the two sides aren't equal.

Answer (score 1):

If we use positive integers only for the factorial function:

Expanding $n!(n+1)!$ we get $n!(n!)(n+1) = (n!)^2(n+1)$.
To compare how the two different functions grow, let us compute $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 * (n+1)}$. or $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}(n+1)$. We recognise $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ as the [central binomial coefficient,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) which is always greater than 0 for all positive integers.

Since $n$ is also a positive integer, $n+1$ is a positive integer, so  $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}(n+1)$ is a positive integer. Therefore, $(2n)!$ is always greater than $(n!)(n+1)!$, for $n > 1$ (as @Yves Daoutt mentioned). Indeed, calculating the cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ give $0! = (0!)(1!)$ and $2! = (1!)(2!)$, or $1 = 1$ and $2 =2$ respectively.

Comment: I just wanted to double check my answer here: @prayer smith do you mean 2n! or (2n)!? They are two completely different things.

Comment: I meant   (2n)!  ; it is a typo

Comment: Ignore my answer please.

Comment: Changed answer completely to change $2n!$ to $(2n)!$.

Answer (score 1):

The first values yield

$$2=1\cdot2,\\
24>2\cdot6,\\
720>6\cdot24\\\cdots$$

and by induction

$$(2n)!>n!(n+1)!\\\implies\\(2(n+1))!=(2n)!(2n+1)(2n+2)>n!(n+1)(n+1)!(n+2)=(n+1)!(n+2)!$$

---

Actually, the ratio LHS/RHS asymptotically grows like $4^n$.